# LM324 circuit is not working

Tags: operational-amplifier

My circuit with an LM324 is malfunctioning.

I want to build a very simple charge full indicator as well as a low battery indicator (sensor) using an LM324.

But it is not working.

Below is the diagram, and as well some write-up.

Please help me figure out what could be wrong with the circuit.  Everything seems right to me.

Is it that I have not powered the LM properly, or is it that some specific voltage is needed at the input of the LM324?

I have tried using about 3 LM324 ICs, but the results are all the same.

[image]

Comment: Your voltage reference from the zener doesn't look like it is connected correctly.  Are you getting the correct reference voltage on pin 9?

Comment: @HandyHowie yeah i am getting the right volts on pin 9 but yet is not still working as suppose to, please if you guys have a better simple diagram you can as well show me

Comment: I count six please, but on the other hand there is almost a complete schematic, so that's a plus. On the other hand, ground is pointing up.

Comment: That schematic is hard to read, there is a tool if you edit your question that can help you draw a schematic.

Comment: You appear to have a resistor between Vcc on the LM324 and your 12V source.

Comment: It looks like there is a resistor in series with the V+ pin.  Delete it and make a direct connection.  Also, add decoupling capacitors across the power pins with leads as short as possible.

Comment: The Zener diode won't do anything useful as you have it connected - especially as it is in series with a 1 Meg resistor.

Comment: @AnalogKid please when i connected it directly to the supply 12v my IC started to hit up.

Comment: @HandyHowie and beside how can i add up the decoupling capacitor ?